# How can a parameter's default value reference another parameter?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

How can a parameter's default value reference another parameter? If it cannot, how to work around that?

```
case class A(val x:Int, val y:Int = x*2)
```

Error (reasonably enough):

```
scala> case class B(val x:Int, val y:Int = x*2)
<console>:7: error: not found: value x
   case class B(val x:Int, val y:Int = x*2)
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you asked for the work-around, if it's not obvious how to preserve caseness:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Foo(x: Int, y: Int)
object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int): Foo  = apply(x, 2*x)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined object Foo

scala> Foo(5,6)
res45: Foo = Foo(5,6)

scala> Foo(5)
res46: Foo = Foo(5,10)
```

Comment: I find this method more useful, but I'm giving 0__'s answer the acceptance, because it seems to be more popular.

Comment: Actually, the green check is supposed to mean what solved your problem, however you define that. But I would guess you solved your problem a couple of years ago.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect, I don't know why I switched the green checks.

Comment: Took a second look after all these years. This is definitely the better solution! Giving back the green check!

Answer (score 25):

This requires that you use multiple parameter lists:

```
case class A(x: Int)(y: Int = x*2)
```

Default values can only refer to parameters in preceding lists.

Be careful however with case classes, because their equality only takes into the account the first parameter list, therefore:

```
A(1)() == A(1)(3)  // --> true!!
```

Comment: Nice answer. That's quite a gotcha when using case classes, and it's still not fixed as of 2.11.6.

Comment: Actually, I consider it a useful feature to be able define parameters that do not participate in equality and hash.